# Smart filter with python

Tags: python, optimization, text, filter, python-2.4

Hi
I need filter out all rows that don't contain symbols from huge "necessary" list, example code:

```
def any_it(iterable):
      for element in iterable:
          if element: return True
      return False

regexp = re.compile(r'fruit=([A-Z]+)')
necessary = ['YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'RED', ...] # huge list of 10 000 members
f = open("huge_file", "r") ## file with > 100 000 lines
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

## File rows like, let's say:
# 1 djhds fruit=REDSOMETHING sdkjld
# 2 sdhfkjk fruit=GREENORANGE lkjfldk
# 3 dskjldsj fruit=YELLOWDOG sldkfjsdl
# 4 gfhfg fruit=REDSOMETHINGELSE fgdgdfg

filtered = (line for line in lines if any_it(regexp.findall(line)[0].startswith(x) for x in necessary))
```

I have python 2.4, so I can't use built-in `any()`.
I wait a long time for this filtering, but is there some way to optimize it? For example row 1 and 4 contains "RED.." pattern, if we found that "RED.." pattern is ok, can we skip search in 10000-members list for row 4 the same pattern??
Is there some another way to optimize filtering?
Thank you.
...**edited**...
**UPD:** See real example data in comments to this post.  I'm also interested in sorting by "fruits" the result.  Thanks!
...**end edited**...

Comment: @DominiCane: Can you provide appropriately-sized representative data sets? There may be optimization paths that we can't anticipate because we're not familiar with your data.

Comment: What exactly can I provide? This example is close enough to real situation. This filtering is part of generators chain, that modifies rows in the file. I can't think about the closer example... Guide me what it lacks here..

Comment: Quantity. Real filter items. There are less than 200 different words for colour I could find in the English language.

Comment: Files about one-five millions of rows. Of course not with colors, but with exchange market symbols like "QZF10", "ZT F1:H2" and other lovely strings. The real example row is: msgType=QuoteMsg conType=call exch=206 sym=OZFH1                   Strike=003        12000 fast=normal Quote=026          480 TckSiz=25 SalesCond=Ask BateModifier=Explicit

Comment: How about a sample 100 filter items, 1000 lines of data and the correctly filtered output on pastebin or something?

Comment: 1000 lines of text: http://pastebin.com/4Xs5uK7d

Comment: and 100 lines of "necessary": http://pastebin.com/jt2bU09A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm convinced [Zach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397859/smart-filter-with-python/4398588#4398588) is on the right track. Out of curiosity, I've implemented another version (incorporating Zach's comments about using a dict instead of `bisect`) and folded it into a solution that matches your example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
from trieMatch import PrefixMatch # https://gist.github.com/736416

pm = PrefixMatch(['YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'RED', ]) # huge list of 10 000 members
# if list is static, it might be worth picking "pm" to avoid rebuilding each time

f = open("huge_file.txt", "r") ## file with > 100 000 lines
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

regexp = re.compile(r'^.*?fruit=([A-Z]+)')
filtered = (line for line in lines if pm.match(regexp.match(line).group(1)))
```

For brevity, implementation of `PrefixMatch` is [published here](https://gist.github.com/736416).

If your list of `necessary` prefixes is static or changes infrequently, you can speed up subsequent runs by pickling and reusing the `PickleMatch` object instead of rebuilding it each time.

#### update (on sorted results)

According to the [changelog for Python 2.4](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/whatsnew/node12.html):

> *key* should be a single-parameter function that takes a list element and
>   returns a comparison key for the
>   element. The list is then sorted using
>   the comparison keys.

also, in [the source code, line 1792](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r243/Objects/listobject.c?revision=43414&view=markup):

```
/* Special wrapper to support stable sorting using the decorate-sort-undecorate
   pattern.  Holds a key which is used for comparisons and the original record
   which is returned during the undecorate phase.  By exposing only the key
   .... */
```

This means that your regex pattern is only evaluated once for each entry (not once for each compare), hence it should not be too expensive to do:

```
sorted_generator = sorted(filtered, key=regexp.match(line).group(1))
```

Comment: thanks! Filtering works perfectly! But sorting, surprisingly, is slower that my old "sorted(generator, key=lambda x: regexp.findall(x)[0])". Currently investigating why..

Comment: Does it help if you use `sort(lambda x,y:cmp(x[0],y[0]))` on the mapped list instead of a straight up `sort()`?

Comment: According to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463032//464815#464815) `key=..` for `sort`/`sorted` would already perform map-sort-unmap, so no need to do it yourself. Some of the benchmarks I've run seem to suggest the same. Will remove sorting bit from my answer.

Comment: Found proof that as of Python 2.4, `sorted(key=...)` already does decorate-sort-undecorate. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

If you organized the `necessary` list as a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), then you could look in that trie to check if the `fruit` starts with a valid prefix.  That should be faster than comparing the `fruit` against every prefix.

For example (only mildly tested):

```
import bisect
import re

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.children_values = []
        self.exists = False

    # Based on code at http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html                
    def _index_of(self, ch):
        i = bisect.bisect_left(self.children_values, ch)
        if i != len(self.children_values) and self.children_values[i] == ch:
            return (i, self.children[i])
        return (i, None)

    def add(self, value):
        if len(value) == 0:
            self.exists = True
            return
        i, child = self._index_of(value[0])
        if not child:
            child = Node()
            self.children.insert(i, child)
            self.children_values.insert(i, value[0])
        child.add(value[1:])

    def contains_prefix_of(self, value):
        if self.exists:
            return True
        i, child = self._index_of(value[0])
        if not child:
            return False
        return child.contains_prefix_of(value[1:])

necessary = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'BLACK',
             'LIGHTRED', 'LIGHTGREEN', 'GRAY']

trie = Node()
for value in necessary:
    trie.add(value)

# Find lines that match values in the trie
filtered = []
regexp = re.compile(r'fruit=([A-Z]+)')
for line in open('whatever-file'):
    fruit = regexp.findall(line)[0]
    if trie.contains_prefix_of(fruit):
        filtered.append(line)
```

This changes your algorithm from `O(N * k)`, where `N` is the number of elements of `necessary` and `k` is the length of `fruit`, to just `O(k)` (more or less).  It does take more memory though, but that might be a worthwhile trade-off for your case.

Comment: +1 I'm sure this will give by far the biggest speedup. In the original code, if a line would *not match* the script had to go trough *every* word in `nessesary`. You can find some tested implementations for this too, it's called a patricia or radix tree

Comment: +1 `import bisect` is new to me! Definitely the fastest approach suggested so far.

Comment: @Shawn Yep, and as soon as I submitted this I realized that I could've just used a dict instead of a sorted list, which might be faster due to O(1) lookup instead of O(log(m)) at each Node.  But since you commented I'll leave it as an example of how to use bisect :-)

Comment: @Zach Hirsch, trying your solution now.. What do you mean by using dict and not sorted list?? Can you explain, please?

Comment: @Zach Hirsch, another off-topic question: I need in future to sort this file lines by "fruit"s, could bisect help do it faster than sorted() with key=regexp()?

Comment: @DominiCane I meant to use a dict to store the child/child_values pairs in the Node class instead of using bisect to maintain a sorted list.  It would also simplify the implementation since the _index_of method wouldn't be needed anymore---the add and contains_prefix_of methods could index into the dict directly (which is a O(1)) lookup.

Comment: @DominiCane I wouldn't use a regexp in the key= parameter, that'll probably result in the regexp being evaluated many many times per "fruit", which would be slow.  You could use bisect to write your own sort, but I would create a new class that represents a line in the file, and provides fast access to the "fruit" (e.g. cache the result of the regexp), and sort a list of instances of that with an appropriate key=.

Answer (score 1):

Tested (but unbenchmarked) code:

```
import re
import fileinput

regexp = re.compile(r'^.*?fruit=([A-Z]+)')
necessary = ['YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'RED', ]

filtered = []
for line in fileinput.input(["test.txt"]):
    try:
        key = regexp.match(line).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        continue # no match
    for p in necessary:
        if key.startswith(p):
            filtered.append(line)
            break

# "filtered" now holds your results
print "".join(filtered)
```

Diff to code in question:

1. We do not first load the whole file into memory (as is done when you use `file.readlines()`). Instead, we process each line as the file is read in. I use the `fileinput` module here for brevity, but one can also use `line = file.readline()` and a `while line:` loop.
2. We stop iterating through the `necessary` list once a match is found.
3. We modified the regex pattern and use `re.match` instead of `re.findall`. That's assuming that each line would only contain one "fruit=..." entry.

#### update

If the format of the input file is consistent, you can squeeze out a little more performance by getting rid of regex altogether.

```
try:
    # with line = "2 asdasd fruit=SOMETHING asdasd...."
    key = line.split(" ", 3)[2].split("=")[1]
except:
    continue # no match
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I didn't mention that this generator is only one in the chain of generators, so reading the file is not the bottleneck here. About 2 - function any_it() does the same. And 3 is useful for me here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a simple list of `['fruit=RED','fruit=GREEN'...` etc. with `['fruit='+n for n in necessary]`, then use `in` rather than a regex to test them. I don't think there's any way to do it really quickly, though.

```
filtered = (line for line in f if any(a in line for a in necessary_simple))
```

(The any() function is doing the same thing as your any_it() function)

Oh, and get rid of file.readlines(), just iterate over the file.

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple. Strings "in" operator is really faster. But we anyway should use any_it() function, so finally: filtered = (line for line in f if any_it(a in line for a in necessary_simple)). Other way we get "if [true, true, false, false, true,...]" and it's always True. And in your version "a" variable is referenced before assignment. have you solution without "any()"?

Comment: @DominiCane: Well spotted, I should have tested it. I think any() is the neatest way to do it: your any_it function shouldn't be much slower.

Answer (score 1):

```
filtered=[]
for line in open('huge_file'):
    found=regexp.findall(line)
    if found:
        fruit=found[0]
        for x in necessary:
            if fruit.startswith(x):
                filtered.append(line)
                break
```

or maybe :

```
necessary=['fruit=%s'%x for x in necessary]
filtered=[]
for line in open('huge_file'):
    for x in necessary:
        if x in line:
            filtered.append(line)
            break
```

Comment: I think any_it() function does same thing, no?

Comment: @DominiCane : **any_it** is fine, it's simplier without it tough. In your version **regexp.findall(line)[0]** is called len(necessary) times for each line.

Comment: I think regexp.findall(line)[0] is called until we get True from any_it(), not len(necessary). But your're right about extracting regexp every step, it's slow and unnecessary, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like your code as is since you consider "fruit=COLOR" as a pattern which others does not. I think you want to find some solution like memoization which enables you to skip test for already solved problem but this is not the case I guess.

def any_it(iterable):
      for element in iterable:
          if element: return True
      return False

necessary = ['YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'RED', ...]

predicate = lambda line: any_it("fruit=" + color in line for color in necessary)

filtered = ifilter(predicate, open("testest"))

Comment: Yes, string operations is much faster

Answer (score 0):

Untested code:

```
filtered = []
for line in lines:
    value = line.split('=', 1)[1].split(' ',1)[0]
    if value not in necessary:
        filtered.append(line)
```

That should be faster than pattern matching 10 000 patterns onto a line.
Possibly there are even faster ways. :)

Comment: If the `necessary` list is big, wouldn't a `set` be a better choice for it?

Comment: My understanding was the that value only has to start with any item in necessary, not be equal to it.

Comment: the problem is that value contains part of pattern. "REDSOMETHING" is not in ["RED", "GREEN"], and I can't extract "RED" from "REDSOMETHING", I don't know the length

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, using "startsiwth" is not necessarily faster than pattern matching, so re might be the best solution here. And yeah, that *will* be slow.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't take too long to iterate through 100,000 strings, but I see you have a 10,000 strings list, which means you iterate 10,000 * 100,000 = 1,000,000,000 times the strings, so I don't know what did you expect...
As for your question, if you encounter a word from the list and you only need 1 or more (if you want exacly 1 you need to iterate through the whole list) you **can** skip the rest, it should optimize the search operation.